# Azure Blob auto delete

Tags: azure, blob

i have a blob container in my Azure account, i save my sql translog files into the container. does anyone know how to automatically delete the log files after x days?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [Blob Lifecycle Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal).